# Return an n*n nested array populated with null

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm very lost here. Given a number, n, I have to return an n*n nested array populated with the value null. 
If n is 3:

```
[
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null]
]
```

I am so lost. I've got something like this:

```
function generateMatrix (n) {
  let item = 'null';
  let array1 = [];
  let solution = [];
  array1.push(item.repeat(n));
  solution.push(array1.repeat(n));
  return solution;  
  }
```

I know it isn't right, not only because it's not working, but also because it doesn't make sense and I don't know how to do it. Bear in mind I'm very very junior, just started learning JS.

I've seen [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962086/javascript-creating-multi-dimensional-array-syntax?noredirect=1&lq=1) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228902/duplicate-an-array-an-arbitrary-number-of-times-javascript) threads, but can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So given *n* - you need to loop that many times. Inside each loop, you need to loop again

Comment: `null !== 'null'`!

Comment: You want to first be able to create a row of n `null` - there are various ways such as loops, or you can use `Array.fill` (which loops the array internally), in combination with `Array(n)` which creates an array of length n containing `undefined` but uses `.fill` to change them to `null`, as in the below answer, to output `[null, null, null]` (if n is 3) and then use this same pattern to create a row of rows. So you would fill an array with n `[null, null, null]` to get the matrix you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function generateMatrix (n) {
  let result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      result[i].push(null);
    }
  }
  return result;  
}
console.log(generateMatrix(3));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) methods.

```js
function matrix(n) {
  return Array.from(Array(n), () => Array(n).fill(null))
}

console.log(matrix(3))
```

You can use the same approach to create matrix with `rows x columns` dimensions.

```js
function matrix(rows, cols) {
  return Array.from(Array(rows), () => Array(cols).fill(null))
}

console.log(matrix(2, 4))
console.log(matrix(3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative using the function **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** and the function **[`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)**.

```js
var rows = 3;
var cols = 3;

var matrix = Array.from({length: rows}, () => new Array(cols).fill(null))
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

> `Array.from()` lets you create Arrays from:
>
> - array-like objects (objects with a **`length`** property and indexed elements) or
> - iterable objects (objects where you can get its elements, such as Map and Set).